# automatically check action argument for not null'ess (ASP.Net MVC 4)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Is there a out-of-the-box way to make MVC throw an exception if argument is null.

I want something like:

```
public ActionResult Index([NotNull] string productId) {
    ...
}
```

So instead of doing not-null check inline or using a code contract I would prefer to decorate argument with `NotNull`.

Comment: you could just not check for null and let the code that uses productId naturally throw a null reference exception?

Comment: Doesn't it throw an exception out of the box if the route doesn't fit the specified routes and there is no value specified for the argument??

Comment: @Mike: I would prefer "you forgot to pass productId argument" over "there is a null object somewhere". Plus that null exception can be thrown somewhere deeper than action. I'd rather have meaningful exception closer to the trouble source.

Comment: @Ulises: It does. But suppose I have two arguments. I do not want to create new route for each signature-type of action.